# WPF FileNotFoundException on constructor

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've been trying to launch my app outside of Visual Studio (works fine inside of VS). Published my app, but it crashes on launch. I've learned about event viewer and it shows:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException à AHP_Talker.MainWindow..ctor() Informations sur l'exception : System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException à System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri) à System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri) à System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean) à System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext) à System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Uri, Boolean) à System.Windows.Application.DoStartup() à System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(System.Object) à System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32) à System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate) à System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl() à System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object) à MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(System.Object) à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) à MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) à System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke() à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue() à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) à MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) à MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object) à System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32) à System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate) à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32) à MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr) à MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef) à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame) à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame) à System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object) à System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window) à System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window) à System.Windows.Application.Run() à AHP_Talker.App.Main()

Here's my mainwindow XAML (there's nothing in the backend):

```
<Window x:Class="AHP_Talker.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    WindowState="Maximized"
    WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
    Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
    TextElement.FontWeight="Medium"
    TextElement.FontSize="14"
    FontFamily="{materialDesign:MaterialDesignFont}">
<Frame Name="frame" Source="CustomPage/IdentificationPage.xaml" />
</Window>
```

Also, do I need to copy the resources I use for other pages ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by publish? Also how do the published files compare to your release build output?

Comment: I've selected project->publish->path on my desktop->from CD or DVD->not online. In the setup folder i can find the packages. I searched but don't even know where the program is actually installed

Comment: Can you confirm that the path `CustomPage/IdentificationPage.xaml` is correct and without typos? Consider to use pack uri instead e.g. `pack://application:,,,/CustomPage/IdentificationPage.xaml`. [Pack URIs in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf).

Comment: The program works in vs so the path is good. I've even tried to remove the frame and it still doesn't work

Comment: I had the same exception. The cause was a missing dll file which was referenced in the application. The fix was to copy this dll file to the application folder on the other machine.